# Issue label point with tkz-euclide within foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tkz-euclide

I wish to display some numbered balls, but somehow, whether it's from my missuse of tkz-euclide or foreach, I failed to label the balls correctly.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/B1, 2/0/B2, 4/0/B3, 6/0/B4}
\tkzDefPoints{1/1.732/B5, 5/1.732/B6}
\foreach \color/\numero [count=\index] in {blue/1, orange/2, orange/1, green/1, orange/3, blue/2} {
    \tkzDrawCircle[R, color=black, fill=\color!40](B\index, 1cm)
    \tkzLabelPoint[anchor=center](B\index){\numero}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid using macros like `\color`, which gets used when dealing with the colors internally, as loop variable. If you use e.g. `\coloro` instead there is no problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/B1, 2/0/B2, 4/0/B3, 6/0/B4}
\tkzDefPoints{1/1.732/B5, 5/1.732/B6}
\foreach \coloro/\numero [count=\index] in {blue/1, orange/2, orange/1, green/1, orange/3, blue/2} {
    \tkzDrawCircle[R, color=black, fill=\coloro!40](B\index, 1cm)
    \tkzLabelPoint[anchor=center](B\index){\numero}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]