# TikZ: Why does my pgfmath macro cause errors when used within a node's label text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, tikz-node

I am trying to draw a graph with labels along the edges. To do this, I'm using two foreach loops like in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \newcommand{\nodedist}{2} % in cm
        \newcommand{\nodesize}{.25cm}
        
        \foreach \i in {0,...,6} {
            \pgfmathparse{\i * \nodedist}
            \node[draw, circle, minimum size=\nodesize] (\i) at (\pgfmathresult,0) {$v_\i$};
        }
        
        \foreach \curr in {0,...,5} {
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\next}{\curr + 1}
            \draw[->] (\curr) edge node[above] {$a_{1}$} (\next);
%           \draw[->] (\curr) edge node[above] {$a_{\next}$} (\next);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the second loop, I use the loop variable to calculate the number of the next node. This works for drawing the edges themselves, but when I try to utilize it in the node labels, I get the error:

```
Missing } inserted. }
```

What exactly is going wrong here? After all, it seems to work fine when I use \pgfmathparse and \pgfmathresult.

Comment: This is kind of the same thing as  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620149/issue-label-point-with-tkz-euclide-within-foreach-loop actually. `\next` is already defined by something, and when it is  (locally) redefined, things break -- try a different macro name. I don't know exactly what defines it, and how it is used though ....

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You are right. `\next` is defined in `pgfrcs.code.tex` and used when the libraries that get loaded get determined.

Comment: As @TorbjørnT. said, this is the same mistake as in the linked Q but with `\next` instead of `\color`. The solution is just as simple, use another macro name.